# 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

this is the code I have below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
z = np.linspace(0.20, 0.30, 0.01)
```

and the error I get `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

As it is explained in [the NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), number of samples between the two limits must be specified, not the increments. i.e. the code must be as:

```
z = np.linspace(0.20, 0.30, num=11)
```

Answer (score 0):

The last argument of the np.linspace function is the count of elements to be generated which should be an integer and not a float value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).